# Can I access my environment variables inside a HTML file in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
<img src="{{photoUrl.replace('upload/', 'upload/' + environment.someVariable)}}">
```

I can access my environment variables inside my .TS file like below but it's not recognized in the HTML file.

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';


ngOnInit(): void {
  const something = environment.someVariable;
}
```

Comment: yes just create one property in component then assign the value of your environment
environment = environment.someVarible;

Comment: @Indraraj26, answers go down there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes just create one property in component then assign the value of your environment.

ts:

```
public environment = environment;
```

html:

```
{{environment.someVariable}}
```

Comment: I know that's the easy way, just seeing if there is a way to access the environment variables without creating a new variable inside the .ts file. It seems like there should be a way!? FYI - I have lots of these variables, not just 1 and it would be on multiple pages. So i would be doing lots of variable creation in each .ts file, which is what I'd like to eliminate.

Comment: Short Answer:NO, You can create directive or Pipe, Basically use pipe to alter it i would say according to environment.

Comment: You pass an value it will concat with environment.someVariable return modifiedValue

Comment: That seems like a lot more work as I would have to create a custom pipe. And the environment variables would still have to be read in the custom pipe file, right?

Comment: Yes but with that you will not have to import environment anywhere and create tons of variable.

Comment: Ah ya you're right. I see. Maybe I'll try that...Thanks.